# Safe usage of captured this in constructor lambda in movable types

Tags: c++, lambda

Take this contrived code where we need to create a lambda in a constructor that captures `this` in a movable type:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::string_literals;

namespace
{
class foo
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    explicit foo(std::string key, T val) :
        key_{std::move(key)}
    {
        f_ = [this, v = std::move(val)]() {
            std::cout << key_ << ": " << v << std::endl;
        };
    }

    void print()
    {
        f_();
    }

private:
    std::function<void ()> f_;
    std::string key_;
};
}

int main()
{
    auto f1 = foo("hello", "goodbye"s);
    auto f2 = std::move(f1);
    f2.print();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In this example we're using the lambda for type erasure, but it really doesn't matter - all that's important is that we capture `this` in the lambda in the constructor.

[Running this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c8bb10dd6d2186c) will yield:

```
: goodbye
```

This (I think) is because the `key_` member being printed is the empty shell of the moved-from `f1::key_` i.e. the captured `this` pointer is still pointing to `f1` despite now being inside `f2`.

I can think of several (clunky) ways around this that are circumstance-specific, but is there standard/common/better/etc. way of effectively referring to the owning instance from inside a lambda?

Comment: No, but C++17's prvalue rules should ensure that your clde work as-is. If that's enough for your use case, deleting the move constructor and assignment operator would be a good idea too.

Comment: You may want to consider having `f_` take a `foo*` as a parameter instead of capturing `this`. You can pass `this` to `f_` whenever you call it. You may event want to consider passing `key_` instead.

Comment: Not sure how common it is but making the lambda take a reference to the type it is declared in allows you to control at the call site which object it gets used with.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - simple and effective.  Make it answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution may be to avoid capturing `this` and instead providing it to your function object as an argument. This way your function object can be copied and moved around freely without having to account for which instance owns which function object. The current owner can pass itself to the function when the time comes to call it.

For example, here is what your original example might look like :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

class foo
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    explicit foo(std::string key, T val) :
        key_{ std::move(key) }
    {
        f_ = [v = std::move(val)](foo * const this_ptr) {
            std::cout << this_ptr->key_ << ": " << v << std::endl;
        };
    }

    void print()
    {
        f_(this);
    }

private:
    std::function<void(foo *)> f_;
    std::string key_;
};
```